# Como adicionar quebra de linha usando sed?

Tags: regex, bash, linha-de-comando

Como adicionar uma quebra de linha em um output recebido por pipe, usando sed, apenas para casos que se adequam ao padrão estabelecido?

Utilizei `sed "s/.*oo.*/&\n/"` sem sucesso. O padrão está OK, mas a adição da nova linha não. Eu preciso saber o que colocar ali no lugar onde está `\n`.

Exemplos de resultados que espero:

**Sem Match:**

```
echo 'bravo bar' | sed "s/.*oo.*/&\n/"
```

output esperado:

```
bravo bar
```

**Match:**

```
echo 'foo bar' | sed "s/.*oo.*/&\n/"
```

output esperado:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed 's/.*oo.*/&\'$'\n/g'` mas para pegar `foo` você precisa melhorar o padrão:

```
echo 'foo bar' | sed 's/.*oo/&\'$'\n/g'
```

Comment: Porque precisa dessa parte: `'$'`?

Comment: deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: O ``$`` indica a inclusão de uma nova linha que é complementada com ``\n``

Answer (score 1):

`&` representa TODA a string que casa com o padrão, desse jeito você está apenas adicionando uma quebra de linha ao final da linha.

Isso aqui gera o output esperado:

```
echo 'foo bar' | sed 's/\(.*oo\) \(.*\)/\1\n\2/g'
```

Comment: O output do seu comando é: ``foonbar``

Comment: Não é não... Testado antes de postar.

Comment: Em que OS? No OS X o resultado é ``foonbar``

Comment: Isso pq no Mac a quebra de linha é `\r`, não `\n`. Basta efetuar a troca para que funcione.

Comment: se eu trocar para \r fica ``foorbar``

Comment: Nunca usei OS X, provavelmente é alguma questão com o escaping. Tente com `\\r` e veja o resultado.

Comment: Usarei a outra resposta, mas obrigado assim mesmo!

Comment: Mas funciona com `\\r`? Agora até eu quero saber a resposta

Comment: output: ``foo\rbar``

Comment: a versão padrão do `sed` no OS X não é o `gnu sed`, por isso as diferenças na saída. A saída funciona conforme o esperado no `gnu sed`. Por curiosidade, o `sed` padrão no OS X é o mesmo que é encontrado no FreeBSD.

Comment: @BrunoCoimbra, isso é sempre uma dor de cabeça! felizmente os homebrews e afins tem a versão gnused de facil instalação. Em alguns casos os macs têm o gnused instalado com o nome gsed ou com o nome gnused. A funcionalidade gnused (e a gnu awk) é significativamente mais rica.

Answer (score 1):

Usando Gnu-sed (presente nos linux e fácilmente instalável em todo o lado, e às
vezes com o nome gsed) o exemplo proposto pelo OP funciona com ligeira modificação:

```
sed echo 'foo bar' | sed 's/.*oo/&\n/'
```

output

```
foo
bar
```

O @HenriqueBarcelos apresentou alguns exemplos mais ricos com reutilização de substrings
que obviamente funcioname muito bem em GnuSed.

Para realçar a potencialidade desta questão, junto um exemplo um pouco mais complexo que muda quebras de linha de sítio:

- envolve padrões multilinha
- envolve capturas
- envolve substituições mutilinha.

## Caso de estudo: corrigir as palavras quebradas por translineação

Dado um texto com palavras quebradas:

```
$ cat texto
Exemplo
aqui vai um tex-
to que tem trans-
lineações a dar
com um pau!
```

mudar as continuações de palavra para a linha anterior!

```
$ sed -zre 's/-\n([^ ]+) /\1\n/g'  texto
Exemplo
aqui vai um texto
que tem translineações
a dar
com um pau!
```